# How i set actual value of xAxis in tooltip of highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I am getting the position of `xAxis` label in the `tooltip`

[image]

I need the actual value of `xAxis` label in `tooltip` that is month(Jan-20,Feb-20 etc).

and this is my code: https://jsfiddle.net/hze8r4go/10/
,what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of point Formatter use the following

```
formatter:function () {
        console.log(this);
          const template ="<span style='color:'"+this.points[0].color+"'>"+this.x+" : "+this.y+"</span>";
          console.log(template)
          return template;
        },
```

in the above code use **this** and access remaining value and build the required HTML template and return.

Comment: Ya, we can do this but I am getting xAxis index position in `this.x` , not the actual value of xAxis label.